# How to select dropdown item(combobox) using winappdriver

Tags: java, automation, desktop-application, winappdriver

I am automating desktop application using win app driver. I need to select a value from list of dropdown options. I am able to click on the dropdown but not able to select the drop down item based on the name. I tried implementing using windows element but I am getting error.

```
WindowsElement comboBox= (WindowsElement) winDriver.findElement(fundSponsorCombo);
comboBox.click();
```

Can anyone help me this. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below

```vbnet
WindowsElement comboBox= (WindowsElement) winDriver.findElement(fundSponsorCombo);
comboBox.SendKeys("element to select");
```